# Is there a way to read property file from inside BeanFactoryPostProcessor?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` to create Rest Templates beans at runtime. The configurations for rest templates are placed in a yml file.

```
config:
  banks:
    A1:
      restTemplate:
        connectTimeout: 16000
        socketTimeout: 18000
        maxPerRoute: 10
        maxTotalConnection: 20
    B1:
      restTemplate:
        connectTimeout: 20000
        socketTimeout: 20000
        maxPerRoute: 10
        maxTotalConnection: 2
```

The A1, B1 is dynamic. The property file may have a C1, D1 etc. I implemented `EnvironmentAware`
.But it can only get properties like

```
environment.getProperty("config.banks.A1.restTemplate.connectTimeout");
```

Is there any way to get these dynamic properties in the form of a dto , similar to using `@ConfiguratioProperties`

I even tried the following:

```
 @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(environment.resolvePlaceholders("${catalina.home}") + "/conf/restTemplate_prop.yml"));
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();

        Properties props = bean.getObject();
        Enumeration names = props.propertyNames();

        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = names.nextElement().toString();
            String value = props.getProperty(name);
}
```

But I get the properties as:

[image]

I don't even get all the properties. Is there any way to get the properties in a dto and is there an efficient way to do this?
Note: I am current using spring boot version 1.5.2 so I don't have the Binder API.

Comment: Not in a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` as that executes before the properties are being read by Spring or Spring Boot. So you would need to manually load and bind to a DTO. Also trying to load a YAML file with a `PropertiesLoader` will obviously not work it isn't a properties file but a YAML file. If anything you would need the `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` to load and parse it into a `Properties` object.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config.banks.restTemplate")
public class ApplicationProps {
    
    
    private List<Map<String, Object>> props;
    private List<RestTemplateConfiguration> restTemplateConfigurations;
    
    // getters and setters

    public static class RestTemplateConfiguration {

        private String name;
        private Integer connectTimeout;
        private Integer socketTimeout;
        private Integer maxPerRoute;
        private Integer maxTotalConnection

        // getters and setters

    }
}
```

And then make your yaml to contain a list of complex properties

```
config:
  banks:
      restTemplate:
        -
          name: A1
          connectTimeout: 16000
          socketTimeout: 18000
          maxPerRoute: 10
          maxTotalConnection: 20
      
        - 
          name: B1
          connectTimeout: 20000
          socketTimeout: 20000
          maxPerRoute: 10
          maxTotalConnection: 2
```

Then after application Startup you can `Autowire` ApplicationProps and retrieve from the list of restTemplateConfigurations whatever you like.

Comment: I can't do that. The rest Template needs to be managed by Spring's IOC container.

Comment: @MohendraAmatya that doesn't stand. It's either a singleton where you have 1 set of configuration properties, or there are multiple instances of restTemplate where you initialize manually and select which one to use where also manually

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the first comment I found a way to read and manipulate property file.
I used `YamlPropertiesFactoryBean` API.

```
YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new FileSystemResource(environment.resolvePlaceholders("${catalina.home}") + "/conf/rest_prop.yml"));
        yaml.setResolutionMethod(YamlProcessor.ResolutionMethod.OVERRIDE);
        yaml.afterPropertiesSet();
        Map<Object, Object> yamlProperties = yaml.getObject();
```

Now I just modify the yamlProperties map.
The map is produced as such:

```
config.banks.A1.restTemplate.connectTimeout -> 16000
config.banks.A1.restTemplate.maxPerRoute -> 10
config.banks.A1.restTemplate.maxTotalConnection -> 20
config.banks.A1.restTemplate.socketTimeout -> 18000
config.banks.B1.restTemplate.connectTimeout -> 20000
config.banks.B1.restTemplate.maxPerRoute -> 10
config.banks.B1.restTemplate.maxTotalConnection -> 2
config.banks.B1.restTemplate.socketTimeout -> 20000
```

Then this map can be converted to the object of my choice.